# Microsoft 365 ownerless groups policy email message body rich text format

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, groups, rich-text, group-policy

"Microsoft 365 ownerless groups policy" allows customizing email templates.
Can I make the e-mail more vivid? Is it possible to insert links, make some text bold/italic, use headers etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub-style formatting as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax).
In my experience – both – outlook web-client and outlook desktop app interpret GitHub-wiki-style markup well. E.g.:

```
[Link Text](Url) - will look like a link
# will look like a header #
**Will be bold text**
```